Antidivergence of function is Lipschitz
I was reading this paper https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/11081986X and they claim (page 672 and 673) that the flow field $v$ defined as the antidivergence of the density $\rho$ is Lipschitz continuous on $r>0$ by virtue of the fact that $\rho$ is a radially decreasing measure. I can't seem to make sense of this as it seems highly singular in general near $r=0$. Does anyone have any ideas on how to show this?
